# Импорт данных из файла CSV в JavaScript массив (array)

Tags: javascript, csv

У меня есть файл CSV, который внешне похож на excel таблицу. И там есть данные в два столбца и 500 строк. Нужно прочитать все эти данные и перевести в JavaScript массив (array).

До этого такой вопрос здесь задавали, но либо вопрос был не правильный, либо ответ такой "Скопируйте данные из таблицы в текстовый документ и спарсите его".

Comment: [Полный гугл вопросов и ответов](https://www.google.ru/search?q=javascript+csv+parser&oq=javascript+csv+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i60j0l4.7029j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Почему ты думаешь, что твоя проблема униакальна?

Comment: Прокаченные гуру могут решить это одной строкой. Неужели на десяток строк нет в гугле ответа? Вот, например, отличный ответ на SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8493195/6275986